# Can an Android app see the phone's SMS e-mail address?

Tags: android, android-permissions

It's possible to send an e-mail which a phone receives as an SMS by sending to (in the case of Verizon) 2125551212@vtext.com, and when I use the SMS app to send to an e-mail address, that's what shows up as the sending account.  ([This site](http://www.emailtextmessages.com/) has a list of the *"@telcoName.com"* addresses for various other carriers.)   Is there a way for an app to know that "2125551212@vtext.com" address of the phone that it is on, *WITHOUT* having to send out an e-mail over SMS first and then be told whom its sent message came from?

Is there a particular permission that a developer would use to determine this info?

Comment: I thinks this is a Verizon service, not related in anyway with android. It is better if you directly in your app, ask the user the information

Comment: Not limited to Verizon at all.  [This site](http://www.emailtextmessages.com/) among many others shows that EVERY carrier can do the same thing.  The whole point of hoping to accomplish this by getting the info from the OS is so that we do NOT have to ask the user -- who has a remarkable ability to mis-type things, and even mis-remember stuff like what carrier their phone is on, or what IS the phone # for a lesser-used device.  I can get this info by having the phone e-mail my server via SMS, but if there's an easier way to get it, I was hoping to use that instead.

Comment: I'm sorry :) I didn't know about this service... I learnt something, thanks you

Comment: Just start a new SMS message, and instead of a phone number, type your e-mail address in as the recipient, and "hello" or whatever as the body, and tap SEND.  In a moment, you'll see an e-mail message from your Text Messaging address.  You can likewise reply, sending to your SMS from your e-mail account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some other research, it appears that the answer is NO: the phone does NOT "know" the email address that will reach its SMS app.  This info can be determined by asking the user his phone number and cellular carrier (looking up the "@whatever.com" part in the website I posted in the question), OR you can have the app send an SMS to an email address on a cooperating code server, which then "tells" the app what email address it just got a message from.

But the Android operating system in the phone doesn't have this information available itself, so the app can't get it from the OS.